# DataTable - Invalid Json Response

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am trying to make a dynamic master-detail data table and am getting stuck creating the master table, let alone the detail one!

I am using C# web service to fetch the data and keep getting "Invalid JSON Response" error. I used Chrome developer tool and there is no error getting the data.

Web service API returns the data as JSON sting:

```
"[{\"Name\":\"County Tax\",\"ExpenseTypeID\":37},{\"Name\":\"Education\",\"ExpenseTypeID\":36},{\"Name\":\"Medical\",\"ExpenseTypeID\":35}]"
```

And when I check XHR Response in Chrome, it shows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">[{"Name":"County Tax","ExpenseTypeID":37},{"Name":"Education","ExpenseTypeID":36},{"Name":"Medical","ExpenseTypeID":35}]</string>
```

I used JSONLint to validate the JSON and it validates (minus the <string ...>...</string>).

This is how the code is setup:

```
<table id="typesDataTable" class="table table-responsive table-striped table-bordered table-hover" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Expense Type</th>
            <th style="display: none">ExpenseTypeID</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Javascript:

```
var typesDataTable = new Object;

$(document).ready(function () {
    buildTypesDataTable();
    addTypesDataTableListener();
} );

function buildTypesDataTable() {debugger
    if ($.isEmptyObject(typesDataTable)) {
        typesDataTable = $("#typesDataTable").DataTable({
            lengthMenu: [[10, 25, 50, 100], [10, 25, 50, 100]],
            pageLength: 10,
            dom: "tip",
            serverSide: true,
            pagingType: "simple",
            autowidth: false,
            language: {
                emptyTable: "No Expense Types were found."
            },
            ajax: {
                url: "../services/exp.asmx/GetAllExpenseTypes",
                type: "POST"
            },
            columns: [
                {
                    className: 'details-control',
                    orderable: false,
                    data: null,
                    width: "5%",
                    defaultContent: '<img class="details-control-mouseover" src="../assets/images/details_transparent_background.png" title="Click to see included parts." alt="Click to see included parts."/>'
                },
                { data: "Name", width: "85%" },
                { data: "ExpenseTypeID", "visible": false, "searchable": false }
            ],
            order: [[1, "asc"]]
        });
    }
}

function addTypesDataTableListener() {
    // Add event listener for opening and closing details
    $('#typesDataTable tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        var row = typesDataTable.row(tr);

        if (row.child.isShown()) {
            // This row is already open - close it
            row.child.hide();
            tr.removeClass('shown');
        }
        else {
            // Add the html table shell of the datatable.
            row.child(formatTypesDataTableDetailRow(iTableCounter)).show();

            //show the datatable row.
            tr.addClass('shown');

            // try datatable stuff
            buildSubTypesDataTable(row.data(), iTableCounter);
            iTableCounter = iTableCounter + 1;
        }
    });
}
```

**Update - the fix**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var url = "../services/exp.asmx/GetAllExpenseTypes";
    var params = '';
    populteTypesTable(url, params);
    //buildTypesDataTable();
    addTypesDataTableListener();
} );


var tblExpType = $("#typesDataTable").DataTable({
    jQueryUI: true,
    data: [],
    dom: 'lfrtip',
    stateSave: true,
    stateDuration: 60 * 10,
    "lengthMenu": [[10, 20, 50, -1], [10, 20, 50, "All"]],
    order: [ [1, "asc"]],
    autoWidth: false,
    pagingType: "full_numbers",
    "oLanguage": {
        "sEmptyTable": "No Expense Types were found."
    },
    "columns": [
        {
            "className": 'details-control',
            "orderable": false,
            "data": null,
            "defaultContent": ''
        }, {
            "data": "Name"
        }, {
            "data": "ExpenseTypeID"
        }
    ],
    "columnDefs": [
        {
            "targets": [2],
            "visible": false,
            "searchable": false
        },
        {
            "width": "5%",
            "targets": [0]
        },
        {
            "width": "85%",
            "targets": [1]
        }
    ],
    "pageLength": -1,
    processing: true,
    deferRender: true
});

function populteTypesTable(ws_url, parameters) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: ws_url,
        cache: false,
        data: parameters,
    }).done(function (result) {debugger
        tblExpType.clear().draw();
        if (!result || result.d === "") {
            $('#divType').hide();
        }
        else {
            jResult = JSON.parse(result.d); // This is what I needed to get the correct JSON string
            tblExpType.rows.add(jResult).draw();
            tblExpType.columns([2]).visible(false);
            var currPage = parseInt($('#hfCurrPage').val());
            tblExpType.page(currPage).draw(false);
        }
    }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {debugger
        alert(textStatus + ' - ' + errorThrown + '\n' + jqXHR.responseText);
    });
}
```

Comment: Do you parse you response back to json using `JSON.parse()`?

Comment: I do not know about DataTable, but should not the XHR response be raw JSON text? ie, without the <string> XML tag?

Comment: If there are no console errors then the json format is not correct and it cannot be displayed using datatable

Comment: I too think this is my problem; need to do a JSON.parse() but not sure where!

Comment: @NoBullMan i have checked the documentation of datatable and the data format should be like `{ "data":[  [col1text,col2text . . .], [ ... ]  ] }`

Comment: I see no console errors. I check "NetworK and it shows status 200 (success), type "XHR", response header shows "text/XML"

Comment: @MariosNikolaou are you referring to Columns:[ {data: ...}, ...]?

Comment: I fixed the issue, should I update my post with the fix for posterity?

Comment: Surely you should be sending a JSON response not an XML one? I.E `content-type:application/json`

Comment: @NoBullMan can you explain what was going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the json data from API and but then convert it as i did below and then set it as source to DataTable. Check the example below.

```js
  var data = [{"Name":"County Tax","ExpenseTypeID":37},{"Name":"Education","ExpenseTypeID":36},{"Name":"Medical","ExpenseTypeID":35}];       
  var typesDataTable = new Object;
            
  let dataSet = [];
    
  data.forEach(el =>{
    let subArr = [];
    for( let[key,val] of Object.entries(el)){
              subArr.push(val);
    }
    dataSet.push(subArr);
  });

  //console.log(arr);
  $('#example').DataTable( {
        data: dataSet,
        columns: [
            { title: "Name" },
            { title: "ExpenseTypeID" }
        ]
    } );
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<table id="example" class="display" width="100%"></table>
```

Comment: @Moob I do send it as JSON, after web service gets the data in C# data table, I do: return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt).

Comment: Marios, I already fixed the issue but since you posted a solution that seems to also fix the issue, I will mark it as answer to get the credit for it.